# Turn a signed byte into an unsigned half-byte

Tags: java, bit, unsigned

So I have asmall problem here, and I have no clue what could be wrong.
Thats why I'm asking if this (what I'll show you now) ist correct.
I'm turning Binary Files into Byte Lists, so that I can turn those bytes into half bytes.
For Example:
If I get 96 as decimal number (60 as hexadecimal) I want to get 6 and 0 out of it. The same thing with 127 (hex:7F) - I want to get 7 and 15. To achieve this I wrote the following code:
You'll notice, that I need "unsigned bytes" for this in order to work

```
System.out.println((byte) ((UnsignedByte.unsignedToBytes(b) - (UnsignedByte.unsignedToBytes(b) % 16)) / 16));
System.out.println((byte) (UnsignedByte.unsignedToBytes(b) % 16));

public static int unsignedToBytes(byte b) {
    return b & 0xFF;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this not a Problem?

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: I'm getting false values at wrong coordinates and I just want to know if the problem lies here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bit shifting and bitwise operations:

- To get the lower four bits, use `lowerNibble = wholeByte & 0x0F`
- To get the upper four bits, use `upperNibble = (wholeByte >> 4) & 0x0F`

This disregards the sign, because the upper portion of the number is truncated off by `& 0x0F`.

Comment: @RoiEX Absolutely, it does.